# Java HashMaps with bukkit

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit

And how to add 2 enchantments at once in bukkit with

```
myItem.addEnchantments( Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 1 /* TODO Here goes 2nd enchantment */ );
```

'addEnchantments' accepts 'addEnchantments(Map < Enchantment, int >)'

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Add 2 things to HashMap at once as it follows in http://jd.bukkit.org/doxygen/d9/da1/classorg_1_1bukkit_1_1inventory_1_1ItemStack.html#ab336f52b2c29fb57c7ee77fbd3d38e3f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rather use `addEnchantment` twice (or more):

```
myItem.addEnchantment(Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 1);
myItem.addEnchantment(Enchantment.THRONS, 2);
```

If you insist on using `addEnchantments` you'll need to create a map, populate it and pass it:

```
Map<Enhancement, Integer> map = new HashMap<Enhancement, Integer>();
map.put(Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 1);
map.put(Enchantment.THRONS, 2);

myItem.addEnchantments(map);
```

In your case, I would go with option 1

Comment: Great, thanks! By the way do you know how to convert string to HashMap? ;-) I want to store enchantments in DB

Comment: There isn't really anything built in Java to do that

Comment: I guess I will do loop to work with exploded string to add it to new HashMap ;-)

Comment: Would definitely not advise storing split strings all over the database and constructing a `HashMap` at runtime. Instead have a table for player data (ie `players`) and have another table dedicated to enchantment data, you can then use a foreign key to reference the `id` or `username` field on the `players` table from inside of the table used for enchantments. You could then query what enchantments a player has by using `SELECT enchantment_id, enchantment_level FROM enchantments WHERE player_id = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

@John Smith's second question: (How to convert string to hashmap)
You can convert hashmap to string but java (as I know) doesn't have string to hashmap. You can make a function that does this (might be impossible) or make a couple functions that convert hashmap to string and string to hashmap. In this case you want a hashmap with Enchantment and an Integer, so you would simply do something like this:

```
public /*static*/ String hashMapToString(HashMap<Enchantment, Integer> hashMap) {
    StringBuilder serializedString = new StringBuilder();
    for (Enchantment enchant : hashMap.keySet()) {
        serializedString.append(enchant.getName() + "<>" + hashMap.get(enchant) + ";");
    }
    return serializedString.toString();
}
```

then you would create a function to convert that back to a hashmap:

```
public /*static*/ HashMap<Enchantment, Integer> stringToHashMap(String hashMapString) {
    HashMap<Enchantment, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String split : hashMapString.split(";")) {
        String[] splited = split.split("<>");
        hashMap.put(Enchantment.getByName(splited[0]), Integer.valueOf(splited[1]))
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

You can even make them static (remove the comment marks and if you don't want it at all just remove what is inside the comment marks with the comment marks)